# Export-SPWeb ItemUrl Pathing Differences

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

To get the powershell `Export-SpWeb` command to work against the root one has to do this format:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://sharepoint.Contoso.com" -ItemUrl "/Documents" -Path "C:\..."
```

and for that the `-ItemUrl` requires a `/` (forward slash). Otherwise without the slash it fails.

But when one is running it against a site collection

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://sharepoint.Contoso.com/Sites/Omega" -ItemUrl "Main" -Path "C:\..."
```

the `ItemUrl` does not require a `/`. Conversely it will fail if one adds a `/`.

---

Why is a slash ever needed? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quote from  MSDN Blogs [Export-SPWeb Syntax Changes Between Root Site and Sub Sites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/briangre/2014/03/18/export-spweb-syntax-changes-between-root-site-and-sub-sites/) on this issue:

> If you care to know, basically under the covers the Export-SPWeb
>   cmdlet will call SPWeb.GetList(), but prior to calling that function
>   it will prepend the SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl and an extra “/” if the
>   string in ItemUrl does not have a leading “/”. In short, to be safe if
>   you always set the ItemUrl parameter to the server relative url and
>   then path to the list, it should always work regardless of web
>   location.

Comment: Haven't seen that link, it may be the root of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are actually two separate errors which occur behind the scenes and IMHO that Microsoft should fix them:

1. When dealing with the `Identity` and it is just the base URL `http://sharepoint.contoso.com` and a slash in `ItemUrl` is not added the `Export-SPWeb` has an internally (*read unhandled*) error of `Export-SPWeb : <nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>` which meands nothing to an end user.
2. When the user adds a `/` to a relative pathed lcation `Export-SPWeb` can't handle it and reports `The URL provided is invalid. Only valid URLs that are site collections or sites are allowed to be exported using stsadm.exe.`

The second error is not a full failure and is more useful. But it should not mention `stsadm.exe` for site administration at all.